# finding a repeating integer in an array

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

Hi managed to make my program checked if i have repeated 8's. I also want to print out how many repeated 8's i have stored in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    bool digit_seen[10] = {false};
    int digit=0;
    long n;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    while (n>0)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        if (digit_seen[digit])
        {
            break;
        }
        digit_seen[digit] = true;
        n/=10;
    }

    if (n>0 && digit ==8)
    {
        printf("Repeated 8's");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No 8's found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: instead of `digit_seen[digit]=true`, try `digit_count[digit]++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you want to know the number of occurences a 8 is in your number. Like 88 has 2 8s. If that's the case, I don't see why you use a boolean array. First, you need a counter. Second, you need to know if digit is 8 for every digit and increment this counter if that's an 8. Here's an example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    int digit=0;
    long n;
    int counter = 0;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    while (n>0)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        if(digit == 8)
        {
            counter++;
        }

        n/=10;
    }

    if (counter > 0)
    {
        printf("Repeated 8's");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No 8's found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, counter would have the number of occurrences of 8s in your number. Just display it in the printf and it's done.

EDIT : here's a solution using an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int digit = 0;
    long n;
    int arrayNumber[10] = {0};

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    while (n>0)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        arrayNumber[digit]++;

        n /= 10;
    }

    if (arrayNumber[8] > 0)
    {
        printf("Repeated 8's");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No 8's found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This way, you would know occurrence of every number from 0 to 9 in your integer. I'd also point out that you need to define what is a repeated number. If it's when there's at least 2 occurrence, you need to change `arrayNumber[8] > 0` by `arrayNumber[8] > 1`

Comment: is there a way of solving it using array? like going through every element to check if there is an 8 then print all the 8's out?

Comment: You want to know every position of an 8 in your number? Otherwise, if you only print 8s without any other information, add a printf in the if block and you're done. If you want to know every position of an 8, I think printing the number in a char array would be better. and iterate through it with a for loop.

Comment: My assignment doesn't specifically state i need the position but it does state i need to use array.

Comment: I edited my post according to the information you gave me

Comment: Oh and note that it will work only for the range of a long, if your number may have an unlimited number of digits, I'd suggest you use a char array.

Comment: Hi, ive tried your code and it doesnt really work. I tried with 1235 and it still prints me repeated 8s.

Comment: I forgot to add an initialization on the array : int arrayNumber[10] = { 0 }; I dunno which compiler you use though, but it works on Visual Studio now. If you have any other problem, hit me.